# Sorbet-rails not generating RBI's for rails has_many, belongs_to, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typechecking, sorbet

Maybe there's something in the initialization process that I missed, but `sorbet-rails` seems to having trouble generating methods for some of the default rails methods (e.g. `has_many`, `belongs_to`, `validates`, etc.). I can see that the corresponding generated association is generated, but I get type complaints that the main methods do not exist.

e.g. a class like this:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
```

I can see the auto generated sigil in role.rbi

```
  sig { returns(::User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy) }
  def users; end
```

However this is the error I get when checking types:

```
Method has_and_belongs_to_many does not exist on T.class_of(Role) https://srb.help/7003
     3 |  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is an error with `sorbet` not knowing that `has_and_belongs_to_many` method exists. Usually this is provided by `sorbet` itself. I can see the signature of this method is defined in sorbet-typed's [activerecord.rbi](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet-typed/blob/32b68bf17f44d28495ceb7060e5731939db629d1/lib/activerecord/all/activerecord.rbi#L173). In your repo it should be under this path:

```
sorbet/rbi/sorbet-typed/lib/activerecord/all/activerecord.rbi
```

Can you check if the file exists in your repo? if not, you could try running `srb rbi sorbet-typed` (following the [rbi files doc](https://sorbet.org/docs/rbi))

```
Method has_and_belongs_to_many does not exist on T.class_of(Role) https://srb.help/7003
     3 |  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Ah I wasn't sure if this was being brought in by `sorbet-rails` (which I see you're the creator of!) or `sorbet` itself. The file does already exist at `sorbet/rbi/sorbet-typed/lib/activerecord/all/activerecord.rbi`

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that autogenerated gemfile rbis could potentially initialize as `typed: ignore`. I think we're good now :)

Comment: It wasn't a direct answer to my issue but it led to it at least. Thanks for all the work you've put into this! My team is excited to try it out

Comment: Thanks :D feel free to ask qn if you run into any issue!